# Event Handler of Spring boot project does not capture the Event in Axon Framework

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices, cqrs, axon

I tried to implement a simple microservice with CQRS design pattern. i used axon framework and spring boot 3.1 for develop this. I divided query and command services into separate projects. At that moment event handler method is not hit by the event. When I check the event in the axon server. It successfully persists there and when I use the same event handler in the command side code base it is successfully working (The query services are working fine for the query handler).
[Command Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJzOD.png) [Command Service property file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrXwH.png) [Query Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AVBm.png) [Query Service property file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43srK.png) [Shared Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuFmD.png)

hope someone will help to find a proper solution on how to hit event handler

Comment: Don't post code as links to images, include the code in your question instead. We are not going to click several links to have an overview of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have configured the event processor to be a subscribing one. A subscribing event processor picks up any event as it's published in the same JVM instance. So in this case, you want to use a streaming event processor, which uses a token to go through the stream of events.